# Shift register explanation (parallel in - serial out)

Tags: digital-logic, shift-register

The task is to implement a 4-bit shift register with parallel input and serial output using JK flip-flops and standard logic gates. The solution is below:

[image]

This is what happens on the output:

[image]

I don't understand what the SHIFT/LOAD is. Can you please explain what happens in this register if we want to input the number 1010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the schematic, SHIFT/LOAD represents mode. 
 
If pin SHIFT/LOAD is set to

- **logic 1** the SR will move it's values.
  (Q0 will shift in Q1, Q1 in Q2, Q2 in Q3, Q3 in O3)
- **logic 0** the SR will read values from pins (D1=Q1,D2=Q2,D3=Q3, Q0/D0 does not depend on SHIFT/LOAD pin)

If we want to input 1010 in the shift register, we will need to use one of two methods.

**Serial way**:

1. Set SHIFT/LOAD to 0 **(t=1)**
2. Set D0 to 0           **(t=1)**
3. SHIFT/LOAD = 1 (Q0 goes in Q1) **(t=2)**
4. Set D0 to 1 (in the following clock cycle, Q1 goes in Q2 and Q0 into Q1) **(t=2)**
5. D0=0 (Q2 in Q3, Q1 in Q2, Q0 in Q1) **(t=3)**
6. D0=1 (Q3 in O3, Q2 in Q3, Q1 in Q2, Q0 into Q1) **(t=4)**

**Parallel way**:

1. Set SHIFT/LOAD = 1 **(t=1)**
2. Set D0=1, D1=0, D2=1, D3=0. **(t=2)**
3. SHIFT/LOAD = 1 **(t=3)**
4. 1010 will be the output of the O3, but in opposite order 0101 **(t=7~8)**

Comment: But why do we need D1, D2 and D3 if all bits are input through D0. It should be a parallel input. I'm sorry if I'm mistaken, I started learning shift registers today.

Comment: You are not mistaken, there are 2 ways of entering data in this schematic.

Comment: So, we can input all bits at once: D0=1, D1=0, D2=1, D3=0 and then change SHIFT/LOAD to 1 and keep it like this till all bits are shifted through Q3?

Comment: Yes we can, but the circuit will get in the value from D0 in the other *blank* places shifted out. Until all bits are shifted through O3.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand what this SHIFT/LOAD is.

Each register has a 2-to-1 multiplexer in front of what is effectively its D input. This multiplexer determines whether the input is

- the output of the previous register (thus implementing the SHIFT function)
- the parallel input (thus implementing the parallel LOAD function)

(For the first register this would be the same thing, so to save pins & logic area this register has only one input.)

Comment: Would SHIFT/LOAD (0 for load, 1 for shift) represent the selection inputs of a multiplexer then, and the information inputs the output of a previous flip-flop and the new input.

Comment: I think you say the same as I explained, but due to your use of English I am not fully sure.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm not a native speaker. I think I understand now. Thanks.